# get_field_object returning empty value

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have an ACF select field named "author" with options that contain both a value and a label. Ex:

```
value1 : Value 1 Label
value2 : Value 2 Label
etc.
```

I can use `get_field('author');` and it returns `value1`. However, I used to use the below code to get the label instead and it stopped working all of the sudden:

```
$author = get_field_object('author');
echo $author['label'];
```

Any thoughts as to what I'm doing wrong? I created an if statement to check if anything exists in $author and it's consistently empty now.

Comment: Try a `var_dump($author)`? Guessing it's not what you think it is. Maybe it is returning an object like the name suggests? Otherwise, leverage `isset()`?

Comment: `var_dump` is returning `bool(false)`.. Does that indicate no value? I checked the documentation on ACF's website for `get_field_object()` and I'm following it exactly. Weirdly it used to work fine.

Comment: seeing: "In some circumstances it may be necessary to load a field by its key, such as when a value has not yet been saved.". Don't know ACF. Is there a method that can list all the `$selector` values? A `get_fields()` on the form object?

Comment: Figured out what was going on.. Simply updating a post made the fields appear. So, the code was fine. Guess I just need to update all posts to force the data to refresh in some way?

Comment: "Guess I just need to update all posts to force the data to refresh in some way" - ACF stores two separate keys for each item, the friendly name and the internal/ugly field key. If something hasn't been saved yet, including if you create new fields after content exists, it is possible that the friendly name might not work as you expect, however the field key should always work. So yes, saving these items does "kick things", but just know that there could be other cases.